# how to print each value in each column just by loop

Tags: r

Below is my code:

```
my.dataset1<- data.frame(site=c(11,12,13,14),
                     season=c(21,22,23,24),
                     PH=c(1,2,3,4))


for i in names(my.dataset1){
  for (j in nrow(my.dataset1)) {
           print(my.dataset1$i[j])

       }
}
```

What i want is that it can print the results:

```
11

12

13

14

21

22

23

24

1

2

3

4
```

what I actually get is

```
null
```

It does not work. I want to get the results just by for loop!

Comment: `for(j in names(mydataset)) {for(i in 1:nrow(mydataset)) print(mydataset[i,j])}`

Comment: You want `for (j in 1:nrow(mydataset))`. @Onyambu replacing `names()` with `length()` move the problem. `names()` will work, but if you need `1:length()` not just `length()`.

Comment: Also, you can't ever use `$` with variables, just use `mydataset[j, i]` as Onyambu suggests.

Comment: A simpler way to get a similar result would be `unname(unlist(mydataset))`, this prints them all in a single vector rather than one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

Loop syntax must be modified. `names` in the first line of loop should be also replaced with `ncol()`. This will work for you.

```
my.dataset1<- data.frame(site=c(11,12,13,14),
                         season=c(21,22,23,24),
                         PH=c(1,2,3,4))


for (i in 1:ncol(my.dataset1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(my.dataset1)) {
    print(my.dataset1[j,i])

  }
}
```